# Envoy to proxy TCP to a TLS desination

Tags: tcp, proxy, envoyproxy

Can envoy be used in the following scenario?
TCP client -> Envoy (TLS upgrade) -> TLS / Public Server (like stackoverflow.com)

This is similar to stunnel to provide TLS to applications unaware of TLS. I couldn't come across any examples of this in TCP, I did see some in https.